# Order of coset is greater than number of cosets in $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4/\langle(0,1)\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$$\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4/\langle(0,1)\rangle$$

Since $\langle(0,1)\rangle$ has order $4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4$ has 8 elements, the quotient has $\frac{8}{4} = 2$ elements. However, when I calculate the order of the coset:

$$(0,1)+\langle(0,1)\rangle$$

I have the following elements:

$$(0,1)+\langle(0,1)\rangle$$
$$(0,2)+\langle(0,1)\rangle$$
$$(0,3)+\langle(0,1)\rangle$$
$$(0,0)+\langle(0,1)\rangle$$

so it must have order $4$

But the quotient is a group with just $2$ cosets. How is it possible?

Am I confusing something? I know that the group generated by some element must have an order that divides the order of the group, which is $2$. So why it has order $4$?

Comment: You've listed the same element 4 times. You want to look at $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$.

Comment: So how do I calculate the order of a coset?

Comment: I must sum things until they become another coset?

Comment: The only nonzero coset here is $(1,0)+\langle (0,1)\rangle$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Now suppose $(\mathbb{Z}_2\mathbb{Z}_4)/\langle(1,2)\rangle$, the elements in the $0$ coset are just $(0,0),(1,2)$. So if I take $(0,1)+\langle(1,2)\rangle$ and add itself to it more times, I get: $(0,2),(0,3),(0,0)$, so the order of this coset is $4$, right?

Comment: @TedShifrin because $(0,0)$ is the first element that appears and is in the coset $0$

Comment: Through your profile, I saw that you have asked two questions about cosets yesterday. Please do check properly the properties of cosets or technique on finding cosets of a subgroup through reference books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\langle (0,1) \rangle=\{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3)\}$.
So the four elements listed in your problem is actually the same cosets.

Try to verify the following:

> If $g\in H$, then $g+H=H$

So the first coset is $\langle (0,1) \rangle$. Since the subgroup has only two cosets, so choose an element not in $\langle (0,1) \rangle$ to form another coset. To be easy, we can choose $(1,0)$ so that $(1,0)+\langle (0,1) \rangle$ is another coset.